# How to hide an element in WPF FlowDocument?

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

Can any one tell me how I can hide an element (such as a Paragraph or a Table) in a WPF `FlowDocument`? There is no `Visibility` property associated with these elements.

Comment: i think this is the same question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254570/how-can-i-hide-a-paragraph-in-a-flowdocument

Answer (score 0):

[How to collapse a paragraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798262/how-to-collapse-a-paragraph)

Check above URL.

or you just put condition in code so it will not add that paragraph